# Install4j pkcs11 support for code signing

Tags: install4j

We would like to use a GlobalSign EV Certificate for code signing Windows and Mac installation programs. At the moment it looks like instal4j only support pkcs12 key stores. Are there any plan or ongoing development to be able to use EV Certificates from pkcs11 tokens in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

install4j 8.x will support PKCS11 in the near future. I cannot give a specific release date at this time.

As a workaround, use the native signing tools in the "Executable processing" step in the Windows media wizard.

Comment: Thanks for fast info Ingo!

Comment: We were thinking about using jsign in the Executable Processing for the Windows installation programs. But what about the Mac dmg files? Is using MacOS codesign of the install4j created and unsigned installation image the way to go?

Regards,
Tamas

Comment: You don't need PKCS11 for macOS media files. You have to sign them with the Developer ID certificate from Apple which does not come with a hardware module.